# Where obtain Real Time Stock Quote

Tags: android

I want to do an app for android that take the Real Time Stock Quote like this app
http://www.androidtapp.com/tag/streaming-real-time-stock-quotes/

But I don't know how to obtain the values of stock quote. Like rss or read xml

any idea or suggestion?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [Yahoo solution](http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/) (RSS feeds, and here's a simple [example](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm)), and there's always [Google Finance](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/), which is pretty fancy. Both were pretty easy to find with a Google search. *cough*

Comment: Is there any provision for Indian Stock quotes as well on BSE/NSE?

Answer (score 0):

I was aware of Yahoo solutions, Googles looks good too. If none of them do what you want a third party feed from somewhere like [Investis](http://www.investis.com/) may help but it does come with costs